# Как сделать квадрат вокруг квадрата?

Tags: python, opencv

Что нужно сделать, чтобы второй квадрат был больше первого (с фиксированным отступом) и первый находился в центре второго?

```
Rectangles = cv2.rectangle(image_copy, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)

Rectangles2 = cv2.rectangle(Rectangles, (x+10, y-10), ((x + w)+10, (y + h)-10), (0, 255, 0), 2)#overlay for black color detection
```

Comment: "евадрат вокрук"? серьезно?

Comment: @strawdog -  а что делать? За знания Python сейчас платят (хотя-бы гипотетически), а за знания грамматики родного языка -  нет.  Вот и задают школьники вопросы по языкам программирования, игнорируя правила правописания. Поколение Z, так сказать.

Comment: Посмотрите на похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720875/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-around-a-region-of-interest-in-python . Здесь только задача посложней - реализация четырехугольника в определённых областях картинки, но принцип остаётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `h` и `w` положительные, а `d` - размер отступа, то логично, что `d` нужно отнять от начальных координат и прибавить к конечным:

```
Rectangles2 = cv2.rectangle(Rectangles, (x - d, y - d), ((x + w) + d, (y + h) + d), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Полный рабочий пример для `Google Colab`:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

file = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/common/winrt_winphone/assets/logo_70x70.png'
image_copy = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
d = 10
x, y, h, w = 25, 25, 20, 20
Rectangles = cv2.rectangle(image_copy, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)
Rectangles2 = cv2.rectangle(Rectangles, (x - d, y - d), ((x + w) + d, (y + h) + d), (0, 255, 0), 2)#overlay for black color detection
cv2_imshow(Rectangles2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]